# How do I disable double-click to launch iTunes and play song in OS X Mavericks

Tags: itunes, macos, mouse, click

In Maverick, whenever I double-click a track to rename it, iTunes launches and the track plays in iTunes. Very annoying. How do I disable (or re-assign) the double-click to launch/play in iTunes command? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should only open iTunes if you double-click too quickly. An option would be to use the return key to rename the currently selected item to make sure you don't open it accidentaly.

Comment: Simply... don't double-click to edit a name, that's not what it's for. Double-click is to action a file.

Comment: Just wanted to thank Daniel Lawson and Wayfaring Stranger for that solution!Such a relief not to have to deal with iTunes opening all the time, whenever I accidentally double-click an mp3 file.

Answer (score 1):

In the Finder?  You can't.  That's what double-clicking does.  To rename, single-click after selecting the file, or press return.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are clicking too fast.

A 'Double-click' in Finder opens the file or launches the application, etc.

On the other hand, selecting a file/directory, waiting a short period, then clicking again, will allow you to rename it. It's not technically a 'Double-Click' even though you are clicking twice (you could equally use arrows to navigate to the file, then click, for example).

You can alter that delay in System Preferences under the Mouse preference pane. The 'Double-Click speed' slider lets you adjust this. Perhaps you should move the slider closer to the 'Fast' end, which will reduce the chance of it assuming you meant to open the file instead of renaming it when clicking twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent iTunes from opening when you double-click on a track by telling the Finder to open some *other* Application when you double-click on an mp3, or whatever, music file.
A simple Applescript such as

> say "beep"

will do the job. Just open Applescript Editor, type the above script, and **save it as an Application**, e.g. "Beep.app".
Then do a get-info on a music file, and set the "Open with" option to "Beep.app" instead of iTunes. Now try double-clicking on the track. You should see an expanding icon, like the file is opening, but nothing further will happen because "Beep.app" doesn't actually do anything with mp3 files. (Activity Monitor shows Beep actually opens for a few seconds, but it takes up no cpu, and the script itself doesn't execute.)
Once satisfied that the script is working properly, you can go back to your mp3 file's get-info window, and click the "Change All" button to open any double-clicked mp3 with Beep.app instead of iTunes.
That'll stop iTunes from annoying you when you're just trying to change a file's name.

click the "Change all" button to use the "Beep.app" to open all mp3 files

If you don't want the beep, you could even make the AppleScript do nothing:

```
 Tell Application "Finder"
 End Tell
```